# Why needed own php files security, when already given .htaccesss security?

Tags: php, kohana

In kohana framework, in `.htaccess` file is writen

> # Protect application and system files from being viewed

`RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]`

Ok, But why needed this security in each php file :

`<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');`
?

attacker alredy can not open any `.php` file  directly right? (becuase reason is protecte from `.htaccess` RewriteRule)

Comment: PHP files shouldn't really be in trouble even without the `SYSPATH` guard (they will do nothing when evaluated), so especially for those this is like double overkill. But perhaps there are non-PHP files in there as well?

Answer (score 2):

Simpy: It's a fallback. Thats all, but I need more characters, to publish this answer

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the developers wanted to make sure no files can be accessed, no matter if the .htaccess works or not (i.e. disabled `mod_rewrite`).

But for files that only contain class definitions or return/define configuration arrays it is pretty useless anyway, since they don't output anything.

Comment: > It seems like the developers wanted to make sure no files can be accessed, no matter if the .htaccess works or not (i.e. disabled mod_rewrite). ----- But in this case, will not work Routing also, that is, if mod_rewrite disabled , framework will works not succesfully, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but even if it the  .htaccess configuration is required for the framework to run, there is the possibility of a public accessible but incomplete or incorrect installation. This is what they try to address here.

Comment: When `mod_rewrite` is disabled, it will completely break because of unknown directives. What you probably mean is `AllowOverride`

Comment: @KingCrunch Kohana does not use `IfModule` in their `.htaccess`?

Comment: The framework works fine without rewriting enabled. You'll just end up with `index.php` segments in your urls.

Answer (score 2):

You can't be sure - from a framework developer point of view - that the webserver, that your product will be run with, is correctly set up (e.g. .htaccess/RewriteEngine not enabled by AllowOverride or no mod_rewrite ...).

this kind of « second check » is there to ensure that the framework won't leak sensitive data even on badly set up hosting.

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` works only on **Apache**  with `mod_rewrite` enabled. If the server does not meet any of these condition those `SYSPATH` checks comes in handly.

**Note:** not every user can use **Aapche** as web-server. And Not every user has access to `.htaccess`.

There are other alternatives nowadays. Like, nginx.